# How do I make sure my form comes in an array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-push

The idea is that when you click on Volgende, to $getal1, $getal1, $soort, and $antwoord are put in an array. If this is the 2nd time, it 1st and 2nd time there come to be.

**THIS IS MY PHP CODE IN ENGLISH**

```
<?php   
$kind = $_SESSION['kind'];//get the kind of  task choose from +-/*
$class = $_SESSION['class'];//get the number of class
$answers = $_SESSION['answers'];//get the previous answers
if($class == "klas4"){
    $max = 10;
}
if($class == "klas5"){
    $max = 20;
}
if($class == "klas6"){
    $max = 100;
}
$number1 = mt_rand(0,  $max);
$number2 = mt_rand(0,  $max);
?>
<div class="som">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <?php echo $number1 . $kind . $number2 ?>
        <input name="answer" type="number">
        <input type="submit" name="next" value="next"> 
    </form>
</div>
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['next']))
    {   
    $answer = $_POST['next'];
    $answers=array($answers);
    array_push($answers,$number1,$kind, $number2,$answer);

    var_dump($answers);
    $_SESSION['answers']=$answers;
    }
?>
```

If this code is executed, everything comes together.

I hope someone can help

Comment: Use name=data[antwoord]

Comment: It would not work anyway, but then you just send them $antwoord, or did I miss that

Answer (score 0):

Try making your code in English btw, I'm Dutch so I can read it but it's bad practise to do it in your own language.

Also the reason it doesn't work is because $antwoorden isn't defined.
You don't do any calculation.
You save $antwoorden but never get it out of the session again.

can you just post the whole script?
I think you use 1 php file.

I also think you should be more clear in what the script should do.

Comment: I changed my whole code into English, but did not understand what you meant. Can you explain something clear